# Expresión regular para seleccionar y eliminar este comentario {* comentario *}

Tags: regex, prestashop, phpstorm

**Hola, por favor necesito saber como seleccionar este tipo de comentario:**

{** Comentario *}

**con PHPStorm.**

**Por ejemplo:**

Utilizo esta expresión regular: /*(*)?(((?!*/)[\s\S])+)?*/

para seleccionar y eliminar este comentario: /** Comentario */

y funciona perfecto.

También utilizo esta expresión: **//.*$**

para eliminar este tipo de comentario: **// comentario** y funciona bien.

Pero no se que expresión usar para seleccionar y eliminar este tipo de comentario:

{** comentario *}

**Nota:** Los comentarios que trato de eliminar son de Prestashop y utilizo PHPStorm.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

para buscar ese patrón podrías probar con el ejemplo que hice.

Ejemplo:

```
[{**](.*)[}]
```

Explicación:

- `[{**]` --> Busca coincidencia en este grupo de caracteres.
- `(.*)` --> Permite cualquier carácter.
- `[}]` -> Busca coincidencia con este carácter.

Nota: Espero que te sirva de ayuda.